# Reorder list items in flutter dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

hy! I am using reorderable listview to dynamically change list order or swap values by drag and drop. The problem is list item are swaps but not saved in database. I mean i want to change list indexes from database. I am using mysql database. Please help me how can i send network request to database.

> Dart code of Reoderable listview

```
Widget _reorderable() {
return ReorderableListView(
  onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }

      final item = data.removeAt(oldIndex);

      data.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  },
  children: List.generate(data.length, (index) {
    return Card(
      key: ValueKey("$index"),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,

          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 5,
                  right: 10,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  data[index]['sno'].toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 11,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 5,
                    right: 10,
                  ),
                  child: Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline)),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 11,
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 10,
                        right: 0,
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Flexible(
                                child: Text(
                              data[index]['name'].toString(),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              softWrap: true,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                            )),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 5,
                        right: 25,
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 5,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
                          ),

                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 1,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              " Videos",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 8,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          // Padding(

                          //   padding:

                          //       const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),

                          //   child:

                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 20,
                              right: 1,
                              top: 0,
                              bottom: 0,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.star,
                              size: 15,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),

                          //),

                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 0,
                              right: 10,
                              top: 0,
                              bottom: 0,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              data[index]['lecture_views'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 8,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }),
);
}
```

Comment: You can update the list in your database inside `onReorder`. I can't provide you any code on how to update the database because you didn't provide any information about your database and what you did to at least try to change the list's values in the database. You simply have to replace the list in the database with the new list (which is data in your case) after data.insert(newIndex, item); is called.

Comment: Actually i don't have any idea how to update data in database.....and to send network request from onReoder. Please tell me how can i send network request to database and how can i update data from database. BTW i am using php mysql as a backend. I have videos list that are saved on database.

Comment: In this way i am trying to send network request to database                       
 onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
       http.post('url', body: {
         "oldIndex":oldIndex,
         "newIndex":newIndex,
       });
        setState(() {
          if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }

          final item = data.removeAt(oldIndex);

          data.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },

Comment: I've never posted in a php mysql database using flutter before. You need a way to access the database and you have to replace the list with the new list or you can send the old index and new index and have the database do the reordering same as how your onReorder does it.